# HP Officejet 6700

Tags: windows-8, printer

I'm having issues with the HP Officejet 6700. I have removed all drivers and attempted to reinstall them but I keep getting the error that it failed to setup the Network printer.
I'm using the software install suite which I downloaded from HP website.

When running the HP install wizard, it prompts me with the option to setup the printer via "Wireless", "Wired" or "USB" but it keeps prompting "Failed to setup Network printer".

I've managed to get the printer working by installing the printer using Microsoft's "Add printer wizard" but can't find a way to setup the scanner. There's doesn't seem to be a printer driver to pick from when the setup extracted the software files except for DLLs.

How can I get the software to work? Will I have to use the installation CD that came with the printer? Or where can I get the driver for the scanner?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your scanner is installed; did you tried : Start Screen => Type Scan the Windows preinstalled scanner application will be visible in the right corner launch it and verify.

Comment: I've removed all drivers including the scanner. I wish HP didn't make their software do everything for you and not allow manual intervention when required. This is the second time something similar has happened.